# Browser cache of image, served as both favicon, img and background-image

Tags: image, browser, background-image, browser-cache, favicon

I'm using the same image file as favicon, header logo image, and a background image

Chrome developer tools > Network looks like it only downloads and uses *one* instance of the file

But FireFox webdeveloper shows 3 different instances in Page Information > Media

[image]

My question is:

Do browsers generally download the first instance of a file (once) and re-use that, even if it's later served as **other types**? (icon/image/background)

Comment: Interesting question. That would even worth a bug submission on Bugzilla.

Comment: But then I tried FireBug as well. It seems to download only one image (same as Chrome). So it all seems to be good ;) Just a bit confusing webdeveloper>pageinfo>media info

Comment: Oh, ok! I think I got caught by the "But" :)

Comment: And that was the issue! ;) But now I see it's not (after trying FireBug too)